# Radii of Convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

What you be the radius of convergence of the following?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 \cdot x^n$$

I tried it first with ratio test and didn't knew what to do after that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Check this out: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch6.pdf

Comment: Your series is very nearly the second derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$, which has radius of convergence $1$. For power series, the original series and all of its derivatives have the same radius of convergence (see the link in my previous comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n = n^2x^n$

$\implies \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\cdot |x|\to |x|$ as $n\to\infty$

$\implies |x| < 1 \iff \text{series converges}$